# all EBT sutta references to thina middha / sloth & torpor & drowsiness

Tags: sutras

I'm looking to collect all the major sutta references on the 3rd hindrance.

Help me complete the collection:

http://lucid24.org/sted/5niv/5niv3/index.html

What I have so far:

AN 5.78 5 future dangers
AN 5.193 saṅgārava: similes of looking at reflection in bowl of water, 3. Sloth-torpor like water with moss and aquatic plants
AN 7.46 seeing suffering in impermanence
AN 7.61 Pacalāyana: Buddha advises Moggallana with 7 ways to cope: You should have 7 memorized and recite daily.
MN 62 mudita to counter listlessness
MN 70 let only my skin and bones remain... : using vigor to counteract sloth
MN 131 today the effort must be made...: using maraṇa-s-sati 
SN 46.51 Nourishment and starving of Sloth and Torpor
SN 46.53 balancing 7sb☀️ factors
SN 46.55 simile of water covered with moss

Let's restrict the discussion to EBT (early buddhist text, pali, chinese agama, sanskrit, etc.) for now. I'll open up a thread later for Non EBT strategies to deal with sloth later.

Suttas with similes of the 5 hindrances
AN 3.101 simile of 3 levels of gold impurities preventing samadhi and 6ab ⚡☸. 5niv are the 2nd level moderate impurities.
AN 5.23 simile of gold impurities (instead of 'nivarana' calls 5niv 'cittassa upakkilesā') preventing samadhi and 6ab ⚡☸. Also uses keywords from j4 āneñja⚡.
AN 5.51 simile of river split into 5.
DN 2 similes 1. in debt, 2. ill, 3. imprisoned, 4. slave, 5. crossing desert
MN 140 references goldsmith removing impurities, similar to AN 3.101 and AN 3.102, but doesn't call out 5 elements of 5niv by names.
SN 46.33 5 impurities of gold (copper, tin, silver...) make gold (samadhi mind) brittle and unworkable.
SN 46.55 similes for not seeing one's reflection in bowl of water: 1. water is colored with dyes, 2. heated by fire, boiling and bubbling, 3. overgrown with moss, 4. stirred by the wind, 5. murky, muddy

Answer (score 2):

Using [scv-bilara](https://github.com/sc-voice/scv-bilara), I was able to find 131 instances of "thinamiddh (128)" or "thina middh (4)" in the EBTs translated by Ven. Sujato.  Scv-bilara searches EBTs in Pali, Romanized Pali, English and German. It accepts commands such as:

> scripts/search -om1 -d 100 thinamiddh
> scripts/search -om1 -d 100 thina middh

Here are the results sorted in descending relevance. Relevance is computed by density of references per document. This search took about 3 seconds. Scv-bilara is great for generating formal lists. For everyday searches, I find [voice.suttacentral.net](https://voice.suttacentral.net) easier to use.  Voice is a web application built around scv-bilara.

> [MN128:18.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:18.3): ‘Dullness and drowsiness arose in me …
> [MN128:18.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:18.5): I’ll make sure that neither doubt nor loss of focus nor dullness and drowsiness will arise in me again.’
> [MN128:19.8](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:19.8): I’ll make sure that neither doubt nor loss of focus nor dullness and drowsiness nor terror will arise in me again.’
> [MN128:20.8](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:20.8): I’ll make sure that neither doubt nor loss of focus nor dullness and drowsiness nor terror nor excitement will arise in me again.’
> [MN128:21.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:21.5): I’ll make sure that neither doubt nor loss of focus nor dullness and drowsiness nor terror nor excitement nor discomfort will arise in me again.’
> [MN128:22.8](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:22.8): I’ll make sure that neither doubt nor loss of focus nor dullness and drowsiness nor terror nor excitement nor discomfort nor excessive energy will arise in me again.’
> [MN128:23.8](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:23.8): I’ll make sure that neither doubt nor loss of focus nor dullness and drowsiness nor terror nor excitement nor discomfort nor excessive energy nor overly lax energy will arise in me again.’
> [MN128:24.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:24.5): I’ll make sure that neither doubt nor loss of focus nor dullness and drowsiness nor terror nor excitement nor discomfort nor excessive energy nor overly lax energy nor longing will arise in me again.’
> [MN128:25.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:25.5): I’ll make sure that neither doubt nor loss of focus nor dullness and drowsiness nor terror nor excitement nor discomfort nor excessive energy nor overly lax energy nor longing nor perception of diversity will arise in me again.’
> [MN128:26.8](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:26.8): I’ll make sure that neither doubt nor loss of focus nor dullness and drowsiness nor terror nor excitement nor discomfort nor excessive energy nor overly lax energy nor longing nor perception of diversity nor excessive concentration on forms will arise in me again.’
> [MN128:27.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:27.3): dullness and drowsiness,
> [MN128:30.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:30.3): dullness and drowsiness,
> [AN5.56:1.2](https://suttacentral.net/an5.56/en/sujato#an5.56:1.2): “Now, sir, my body feels like it’s drugged. I’m disorientated, the teachings don’t spring to mind, and dullness and drowsiness fill my mind. I lead the spiritual life dissatisfied, and have doubts about the teachings.”
> [AN5.56:2.3](https://suttacentral.net/an5.56/en/sujato#an5.56:2.3): ‘Now, sir, my body feels like it’s drugged. I’m disorientated, the teachings don’t spring to mind, and dullness and drowsiness fill my mind. I lead the spiritual life dissatisfied, and have doubts about the teachings.’”
> [AN5.56:3.1](https://suttacentral.net/an5.56/en/sujato#an5.56:3.1): “That’s how it is, mendicant, when your sense doors are unguarded, you eat too much, you’re not dedicated to wakefulness, you’re unable to discern skillful qualities, and you don’t pursue the development of the qualities that lead to awakening in the evening and toward dawn. Your body feels like it’s drugged. You’re disorientated, the teachings don’t spring to mind, and dullness and drowsiness fill your mind. You lead the spiritual life dissatisfied, and have doubts about the teachings.
> [AN5.56:5.2](https://suttacentral.net/an5.56/en/sujato#an5.56:5.2): “Now, sir, my body doesn’t feel like it’s drugged. I’m not disorientated, the teachings spring to mind, and dullness and drowsiness don’t fill my mind. I lead the spiritual life satisfied, and have no doubts about the teachings.”
> [AN5.56:5.5](https://suttacentral.net/an5.56/en/sujato#an5.56:5.5): ‘Now, sir, my body doesn’t feel like it’s drugged. I’m not disorientated, the teachings spring to mind, and dullness and drowsiness don’t fill my mind. I lead the spiritual life satisfied, and have no doubts about the teachings.’”
> [AN5.56:6.1](https://suttacentral.net/an5.56/en/sujato#an5.56:6.1): “That’s how it is, mendicant, when your sense doors are guarded, you’re moderate in eating, you’re dedicated to wakefulness, you’re able to discern skillful qualities, and you pursue the development of the qualities that lead to awakening in the evening and toward dawn. Your body doesn’t feel like it’s drugged. You’re not disorientated, the teachings spring to mind, and dullness and drowsiness don’t fill your mind. You lead the spiritual life satisfied, and have no doubts about the teachings.
> [AN4.12:2.1](https://suttacentral.net/an4.12/en/sujato#an4.12:2.1): Suppose a mendicant has got rid of desire and ill will while walking, and has given up dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt. Their energy is roused up and unflagging, their mindfulness is established and lucid, their body is tranquil and undisturbed, and their mind is immersed in samādhi. Such a mendicant is said to be ‘keen and prudent, always energetic and determined’ when walking.
> [AN4.12:3.1](https://suttacentral.net/an4.12/en/sujato#an4.12:3.1): Suppose a mendicant has got rid of desire and ill will while standing …
> [AN4.12:4.1](https://suttacentral.net/an4.12/en/sujato#an4.12:4.1): sitting …
> [AN4.12:5.1](https://suttacentral.net/an4.12/en/sujato#an4.12:5.1): and when lying down while awake, and has given up dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt. Their energy is roused up and unflagging, their mindfulness is established and lucid, their body is tranquil and undisturbed, and their mind is immersed in samādhi. Such a mendicant is said to be ‘keen and prudent, always energetic and determined’ when lying down while awake.
> [iti111:4.1](https://suttacentral.net/iti111/en/sujato#iti111:4.1): Suppose a mendicant has got rid of desire and ill will while walking, and has given up dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt. Their energy is roused up and unflagging, their mindfulness is established and lucid, their body is tranquil and undisturbed, and their mind is immersed in samādhi.
> [iti111:5.1](https://suttacentral.net/iti111/en/sujato#iti111:5.1): Suppose a mendicant has got rid of desire and ill will while standing …
> [iti111:6.1](https://suttacentral.net/iti111/en/sujato#iti111:6.1): sitting …
> [iti111:7.1](https://suttacentral.net/iti111/en/sujato#iti111:7.1): or when lying down while awake.
> [AN6.27:4.1](https://suttacentral.net/an6.27/en/sujato#an6.27:4.1): Furthermore, there’s a time when a mendicant’s heart is overcome and mired in dullness and drowsiness …
> [AN1.13:1.1](https://suttacentral.net/an1.13/en/sujato#an1.13:1.1): “Mendicants, I do not see a single thing that gives rise to dullness and drowsiness, or, when they have arisen, makes them increase and grow like discontent, sloth, yawning, sleepiness after eating, and mental sluggishness.
> [AN1.13:1.2](https://suttacentral.net/an1.13/en/sujato#an1.13:1.2): When you have a sluggish mind, dullness and drowsiness arise, and once arisen they increase and grow.”
> [AN1.18:1.1](https://suttacentral.net/an1.18/en/sujato#an1.18:1.1): “Mendicants, I do not see a single thing that prevents dullness and drowsiness from arising, or, when they have arisen, gives them up like the elements of initiative, persistence, and vigor.
> [AN1.18:1.2](https://suttacentral.net/an1.18/en/sujato#an1.18:1.2): When you’re energetic, dullness and drowsiness do not arise, or, if they’ve already arisen, they’re given up.”
> [AN5.193:4.1](https://suttacentral.net/an5.193/en/sujato#an5.193:4.1): Furthermore, when your heart is overcome and mired in dullness and drowsiness … Even hymns that are long-practiced don’t spring to mind, let alone those that are not practiced.
> [AN5.193:4.4](https://suttacentral.net/an5.193/en/sujato#an5.193:4.4): In the same way, when your heart is overcome and mired in dullness and drowsiness … Even hymns that are long-practiced don’t spring to mind, let alone those that are not practiced.
> [AN5.193:9.1](https://suttacentral.net/an5.193/en/sujato#an5.193:9.1): Furthermore, when your heart is not overcome and mired in dullness and drowsiness … Even hymns that are long-unpracticed spring to mind, let alone those that are practiced.
> [AN5.193:9.4](https://suttacentral.net/an5.193/en/sujato#an5.193:9.4): In the same way, when your heart is not overcome and mired in dullness and drowsiness … Even hymns that are long-unpracticed spring to mind, let alone those that are practiced.
> [SN46.55:7.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.55/en/sujato#sn46.55:7.1): Furthermore, when your heart is overcome and mired in dullness and drowsiness … Even hymns that are long-practiced don’t spring to mind, let alone those that are not practiced.
> [SN46.55:8.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.55/en/sujato#sn46.55:8.3): In the same way, when your heart is overcome and mired in dullness and drowsiness … Even hymns that are long-practiced don’t spring to mind, let alone those that are not practiced.
> [SN46.55:17.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.55/en/sujato#sn46.55:17.1): Furthermore, when your heart is not overcome and mired in dullness and drowsiness … Even hymns that are long-unpracticed spring to mind, let alone those that are practiced.
> [SN46.55:18.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.55/en/sujato#sn46.55:18.3): In the same way, when your heart is not overcome and mired in dullness and drowsiness … Even hymns that are long-unpracticed spring to mind, let alone those that are practiced.
> [SN51.20:5.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.20/en/sujato#sn51.20:5.2): It’s when enthusiasm is combined with dullness and drowsiness.
> [SN51.20:22.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.20/en/sujato#sn51.20:22.2): It’s when inquiry is combined with dullness and drowsiness.
> [SN46.51:3.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.51/en/sujato#sn46.51:3.1): And what fuels the arising of dullness and drowsiness, or, when they have arisen, makes them increase and grow?
> [SN46.51:3.4](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.51/en/sujato#sn46.51:3.4): fuels the arising of dullness and drowsiness, or, when they have arisen, makes them increase and grow.
> [SN46.51:15.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.51/en/sujato#sn46.51:15.1): And what starves the arising of dullness and drowsiness, or, when they have arisen, starves their increase and growth?
> [SN46.51:15.4](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.51/en/sujato#sn46.51:15.4): starves the arising of dullness and drowsiness, or, when they have arisen, starves their increase and growth.
> [MN127:16.7](https://suttacentral.net/mn127/en/sujato#mn127:16.7): Their physical discomfort is not completely settled, their dullness and drowsiness is not completely eradicated, and their restlessness and remorse is not completely eliminated.
> [MN127:16.8](https://suttacentral.net/mn127/en/sujato#mn127:16.8): Because of this they practice absorption dimly, as it were.
> [MN127:16.13](https://suttacentral.net/mn127/en/sujato#mn127:16.13): Their physical discomfort is completely settled, their dullness and drowsiness is completely eradicated, and their restlessness and remorse is completely eliminated.
> [MN127:16.14](https://suttacentral.net/mn127/en/sujato#mn127:16.14): Because of this they don’t practice absorption dimly, as it were.
> [AN10.86:12.1](https://suttacentral.net/an10.86/en/sujato#an10.86:12.1): dullness and drowsiness …
> [AN4.61:10.6](https://suttacentral.net/an4.61/en/sujato#an4.61:10.6): dullness and drowsiness …
> [AN4.61:11.3](https://suttacentral.net/an4.61/en/sujato#an4.61:11.3): ‘dullness and drowsiness …’ …
> [MN8:12.22](https://suttacentral.net/mn8/en/sujato#mn8:12.22): ‘Others will be overcome with dullness and drowsiness, but here we will be rid of dullness and drowsiness.’
> [MN8:14.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn8/en/sujato#mn8:14.5): An individual who is attached to their own views, holding them tight, and refusing to let go, gets around it by not being attached to their own views, not holding them tight, but letting them go easily.
> [SN46.8:3.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.8/en/sujato#sn46.8:3.1): As a mendicant rouses up the awakening factor of mindfulness, they understand: ‘My mind is well freed. I’ve eradicated dullness and drowsiness, and eliminated restlessness and remorse. My energy is roused up, and my mind is sharply focused, not sluggish.’ …
> [SN46.8:3.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.8/en/sujato#sn46.8:3.2): As they rouse up the awakening factor of equanimity, they understand: ‘My mind is well freed. I’ve eradicated dullness and drowsiness, and eliminated restlessness and remorse. My energy is roused up, and my mind is sharply focused, not sluggish.’
> [AN6.73:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/an6.73/en/sujato#an6.73:1.3): Desire for sensual pleasures, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [AN6.73:2.3](https://suttacentral.net/an6.73/en/sujato#an6.73:2.3): Desire for sensual pleasures, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [SN46.24:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.24/en/sujato#sn46.24:1.3): dullness and drowsiness,
> [SN46.24:2.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.24/en/sujato#sn46.24:2.3): dullness and drowsiness,
> [ud4.2:4.3](https://suttacentral.net/ud4.2/en/sujato#ud4.2:4.3): overcome with dullness and drowsiness,
> [ud4.2:5.5](https://suttacentral.net/ud4.2/en/sujato#ud4.2:5.5): a mendicant who has overcome dullness and drowsiness
> [AN10.51:3.6](https://suttacentral.net/an10.51/en/sujato#an10.51:3.6): ‘Am I often covetous or not? Am I often malicious or not? Am I often overcome with dullness and drowsiness or not? Am I often restless or not? Am I often doubtful or not? Am I often irritable or not? Am I often corrupted in mind or not? Am I often disturbed in body or not? Am I often energetic or not? Am I often immersed in samādhi or not?’
> [AN10.51:4.2](https://suttacentral.net/an10.51/en/sujato#an10.51:4.2): ‘I am often covetous, malicious, overcome with dullness and drowsiness, restless, doubtful, irritable, defiled in mind, disturbed in body, lazy, and not immersed in samādhi.’ In order to give up those bad, unskillful qualities, they should apply intense enthusiasm, effort, zeal, vigor, perseverance, mindfulness, and situational awareness.
> [AN10.12:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/an10.12/en/sujato#an10.12:1.3): It’s when a mendicant has given up sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [AN10.12:4.2](https://suttacentral.net/an10.12/en/sujato#an10.12:4.2): dullness and drowsiness,
> [AN10.53:6.6](https://suttacentral.net/an10.53/en/sujato#an10.53:6.6): ‘Am I often covetous or not? Am I often malicious or not? Am I often overcome with dullness and drowsiness or not? Am I often restless or not? Am I often doubtful or not? Am I often irritable or not? Am I often defiled in mind or not? Am I often disturbed in body or not? Am I often energetic or not? Am I often immersed in samādhi or not?’
> [AN10.53:7.2](https://suttacentral.net/an10.53/en/sujato#an10.53:7.2): ‘I am often covetous, malicious, overcome with dullness and drowsiness, restless, doubtful, irritable, defiled in mind, disturbed in body, lazy, and not immersed in samādhi.’ In order to give up those bad, unskillful qualities, they should apply intense enthusiasm, effort, zeal, vigor, perseverance, mindfulness, and situational awareness.
> [SN54.12:2.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn54.12/en/sujato#sn54.12:2.6): dullness and drowsiness,
> [SN54.12:4.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn54.12/en/sujato#sn54.12:4.5): dullness and drowsiness,
> [AN11.9:2.12](https://suttacentral.net/an11.9/en/sujato#an11.9:2.12): dullness and drowsiness …
> [AN11.9:3.10](https://suttacentral.net/an11.9/en/sujato#an11.9:3.10): dullness and drowsiness …
> [SN46.2:4.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.2/en/sujato#sn46.2:4.1): And what fuels the arising of dullness and drowsiness, or, when they have arisen, makes them increase and grow?
> [SN46.2:4.4](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.2/en/sujato#sn46.2:4.4): fuels the arising of dullness and drowsiness, or, when they have arisen, makes them increase and grow.
> [MN108:26.7](https://suttacentral.net/mn108/en/sujato#mn108:26.7): dullness and drowsiness …
> [MN4:10.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn4/en/sujato#mn4:10.2): ‘There are ascetics and brahmins overcome with dullness and drowsiness …
> [MN68:6.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn68/en/sujato#mn68:6.2): Take someone who doesn’t achieve the rapture and bliss that are secluded from sensual pleasures and unskillful qualities, or something even more peaceful than that. Their mind is still occupied by desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, doubt, discontent, and sloth.
> [MN68:6.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn68/en/sujato#mn68:6.4): Take someone who does achieve the rapture and bliss that are secluded from sensual pleasures and unskillful qualities, or something even more peaceful than that. Their mind is not occupied by desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, doubt, discontent, and sloth.
> [DN33:2.1.19](https://suttacentral.net/dn33/en/sujato#dn33:2.1.19): sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [DN33:3.3.53](https://suttacentral.net/dn33/en/sujato#dn33:3.3.53): It’s when a mendicant has given up sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [DN34:1.6.21](https://suttacentral.net/dn34/en/sujato#dn34:1.6.21): sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [DN34:2.3.68](https://suttacentral.net/dn34/en/sujato#dn34:2.3.68): It’s when a mendicant has given up sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [SN46.35:1.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.35/en/sujato#sn46.35:1.1): “Mendicants, when you attend improperly, sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt arise, and once arisen they increase and grow.”
> [SN45.177:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.177/en/sujato#sn45.177:1.3): The hindrances of sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [Thag1.74:1.2](https://suttacentral.net/thag1.74/en/sujato#thag1.74:1.2): dullness and drowsiness,
> [AN5.52:1.4](https://suttacentral.net/an5.52/en/sujato#an5.52:1.4): The hindrances of sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [SN46.23:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.23/en/sujato#sn46.23:1.3): When you frequently attend improperly to things that are grounds for dullness and drowsiness, dullness and drowsiness arise, and once arisen they increase and grow.
> [SN46.38:2.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.38/en/sujato#sn46.38:2.2): Sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [AN9.64:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/an9.64/en/sujato#an9.64:1.3): Sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [SN46.37:1.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.37/en/sujato#sn46.37:1.5): dullness and drowsiness,
> [iti34:3.3](https://suttacentral.net/iti34/en/sujato#iti34:3.3): full of dullness and drowsiness,
> [SN46.39:2.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.39/en/sujato#sn46.39:2.5): dullness and drowsiness,
> [SN47.5:1.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn47.5/en/sujato#sn47.5:1.6): The hindrances of sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [AN10.52:4.2](https://suttacentral.net/an10.52/en/sujato#an10.52:4.2): ‘Am I often covetous or not? Am I often malicious or not? Am I often overcome with dullness and drowsiness or not? Am I often restless or not? Am I often doubtful or not? Am I often irritable or not? Am I often defiled in mind or not? Am I often disturbed in body or not? Am I often energetic or not? Am I often immersed in samādhi or not?’
> [AN3.121:3.4](https://suttacentral.net/an3.121/en/sujato#an3.121:3.4): When they have dullness and drowsiness in them they understand ‘I have dullness and drowsiness in me’; and when they don’t have dullness and drowsiness in them they understand ‘I don’t have dullness and drowsiness in me’. They understand how dullness and drowsiness arise; how, when they’ve already arisen, they’re given up; and how, once they’re given up, they don’t arise again in the future.
> [AN5.51:2.5](https://suttacentral.net/an5.51/en/sujato#an5.51:2.5): Dullness and drowsiness …
> [AN9.40:5.3](https://suttacentral.net/an9.40/en/sujato#an9.40:5.3): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind free of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [AN5.23:2.3](https://suttacentral.net/an5.23/en/sujato#an5.23:2.3): Sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [AN6.28:9.1](https://suttacentral.net/an6.28/en/sujato#an6.28:9.1): dullness and drowsiness …
> [AN10.20:3.2](https://suttacentral.net/an10.20/en/sujato#an10.20:3.2): It’s when a mendicant has given up sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [SN46.56:3.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.56/en/sujato#sn46.56:3.2): dullness and drowsiness …
> [SN46.52:9.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.52/en/sujato#sn46.52:9.7): That’s how what is concisely referred to as ‘the hindrance of dullness and drowsiness’ becomes twofold.
> [SN3.24:3.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn3.24/en/sujato#sn3.24:3.3): Sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [AN3.57:4.2](https://suttacentral.net/an3.57/en/sujato#an3.57:4.2): Sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [Thag16.3:13.4](https://suttacentral.net/thag16.3/en/sujato#thag16.3:13.4): and dullness and drowsiness.
> [AN5.75:15.4](https://suttacentral.net/an5.75/en/sujato#an5.75:15.4): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, he meditates with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [MN23:4.20](https://suttacentral.net/mn23/en/sujato#mn23:4.20): the hindrances of sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [MN107:9.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn107/en/sujato#mn107:9.5): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [SNp3.2:13.1](https://suttacentral.net/snp3.2/en/sujato#snp3.2:13.1): Your fifth is dullness and drowsiness,
> [AN4.198:13.6](https://suttacentral.net/an4.198/en/sujato#an4.198:13.6): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [MN48:8.6](https://suttacentral.net/mn48/en/sujato#mn48:8.6): dullness and drowsiness,
> [AN10.99:23.3](https://suttacentral.net/an10.99/en/sujato#an10.99:23.3): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [MN112:17.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn112/en/sujato#mn112:17.3): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, I meditated with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [Thag17.2:30.2](https://suttacentral.net/thag17.2/en/sujato#thag17.2:30.2): dullness and drowsiness,
> [MN27:18.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn27/en/sujato#mn27:18.4): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [MN39:13.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn39/en/sujato#mn39:13.4): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [MN43:20.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn43/en/sujato#mn43:20.3): When a mendicant has entered the first absorption, sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt are given up.
> [MN51:19.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn51/en/sujato#mn51:19.4): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [MN94:21.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn94/en/sujato#mn94:21.4): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [DN10:2.6.3](https://suttacentral.net/dn10/en/sujato#dn10:2.6.3): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [DN13:30.3](https://suttacentral.net/dn13/en/sujato#dn13:30.3): The hindrances of sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [MN10:36.6](https://suttacentral.net/mn10/en/sujato#mn10:36.6): When they have dullness and drowsiness in them, they understand: ‘I have dullness and drowsiness in me.’ When they don’t have dullness and drowsiness in them, they understand: ‘I don’t have dullness and drowsiness in me.’ They understand how dullness and drowsiness arise; how, when they’ve already arisen, they’re given up; and how, once they’re given up, they don’t arise again in the future.
> [MN99:15.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn99/en/sujato#mn99:15.3): The hindrances of sensual desire, ill will, dullness and drowsiness, restlessness and remorse, and doubt.
> [DN25:16.16](https://suttacentral.net/dn25/en/sujato#dn25:16.16): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [MN101:37.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn101/en/sujato#mn101:37.3): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [DN2:68.3](https://suttacentral.net/dn2/en/sujato#dn2:68.3): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [DN22:13.6](https://suttacentral.net/dn22/en/sujato#dn22:13.6): When they have dullness and drowsiness in them, they understand: ‘I have dullness and drowsiness in me.’ When they don’t have dullness and drowsiness in them, they understand: ‘I don’t have dullness and drowsiness in me.’ They understand how dullness and drowsiness arise; how, when they’ve already arisen, they’re given up; and how, once they’re given up, they don’t arise again in the future.
> [MN38:38.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/sujato#mn38:38.4): Giving up dullness and drowsiness, they meditate with a mind rid of dullness and drowsiness, perceiving light, mindful and aware, cleansing the mind of dullness and drowsiness.
> [AN6.66:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/an6.66/en/sujato#an6.66:1.3): Dullness, drowsiness, restlessness, remorse, lack of faith, and negligence.
> [AN6.66:2.3](https://suttacentral.net/an6.66/en/sujato#an6.66:2.3): Dullness, drowsiness, restlessness, remorse, lack of faith, and negligence.
> [SN46.52:9.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.52/en/sujato#sn46.52:9.6): Dullness is a hindrance; and drowsiness is also a hindrance.

Comment: That's nice. I currently use DPR (digital pali reader), but search results only take me to pali (instead of pali + eng as you do above). How do you get that script working on windows pc without linux?

Comment: Without linux it would be difficult. However both Mac and WIndows have unix support for free. MacOS is based on FreeBSD, so it should work, but I haven't tried it. I have tried WIndows Linux and it works fine. We've been talking about providing the scv-bilara capability on the web, but that's a big project that hasn't happened yet.  DPR and SuttaCentral.net are also great, but have different search paradigms.

Comment: Here is the WIndows Linux documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about  Scv-bilara has been tested on Debian and Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The commentaries follow the Dhammasaṅgaṇī in treating both as mental: thīna as sluggishness of citta, middha as sluggishness of cetasikas. But this is in the context of bhāvanā, in connection with the hindrances. Where the terms are used in non-technical everyday contexts the state may be physical, mental, both or unspecified. I think unspecified is probably the most common.

The word "hīna" is a past participle that's been made into a noun. The rules for forming past participles would allow both thīna and thina as the pp. of the verb thīyati.

As for vīriya vs viriya, it's not that they were once two different words that are now taken to be the same, but that they've always been variant forms of the past participle of the same verb, just as 'dreamed' and 'dreamt' have always been variant past participles of 'dream'.

Note that the sutta doesn't identify the nutriment of thīnamiddha with the five items themselves, but rather with frequent unwise attention (ayoniso­ma­nasikā­ra-­bahu­līkāro) to them. And so the immediate cause is wholly mental.

But as to the five, this is how the Vibhaṅga defines them:

> 1. Tattha katamā arati? Pantesu vā senāsanesu aññataraññataresu vā adhikusalesu dhammesu arati aratitā anabhirati anabhiramaṇā ukkaṇṭhitā
>    paritassitā: ayaṃ vuccati “arati”. Therein what is “tedium”? Tedium,
>    having tedium, displeasure, being displeased, dissatisfaction, dread
>    of remote abodes or certain higher skilful dhammas. This is called
>    tedium.
> 2. Tattha katamā tandī? Yā tandī tandiyanā tandimanakatā ālasyaṃ ālasyāyanā ālasyāyitattaṃ: ayaṃ vuccati “tandī”. Therein what is
>    “apathy”? That which is apathy, being apathetic, mental lethargy,
>    idleness, being idle, state of being idle. This is called apathy.
> 3. Tattha katamā vijambhitā? Yā kāyassa jambhanā vijambhanā ānamanā vinamanā sannamanā paṇamanā byādhiyakaṃ: ayaṃ vuccati “vijambhitā”.
>    Therein what is “stretching”? That which is twitching, stretching,
>    bending forward, bending backward, twisting, stretching upwards,
>    fidgeting of the body. This is called stretching.
> 4. Tattha katamo bhattasammado? Yā bhuttāvissa bhattamucchā bhattakilamatho bhattapariḷāho kāyaduṭṭhullaṃ: ayaṃ vuccati
>    “bhattasammado”. Therein what is “after meal drowsiness”? That which
>    in one who has eaten is dizziness because of food, fatigue because of
>    food, feverishness because of food, bodily unfitness. This is called
>    after meal drowsiness.
> 5. Tattha katamaṃ cetaso ca līnattaṃ? Yā cittassa akalyatā akammaññatā olīyanā sallīyanā līnaṃ līyanā līyitattaṃ thinaṃ thīyanā thīyitattaṃ
>    cittassa: idaṃ vuccati “cetaso ca līnattaṃ”. Therein what is “mental
>    sluggishness”? That which is indisposition of consciousness,
>    unwieldiness, drooping, sagging, sluggishness, being sluggish, state
>    of being sluggish, sloth, being slothful, state of consciousness being
>    slothful. This is called mental sluggishness. (Vibh. 17:10:1. U
>    Thittila's translation, with 'restlessness' changed to 'stretching' as
>    the translation of vijambhitā)
>
> https://legacy.suttacentral.net/en/vb17

And from the Dispeller of Delusion:

> The arising of stiffness and torpor comes about through unwise
> bringing to mind in regard to boredom (arati) and so on. "Boredom" is
> a name for dissatisfaction; "languor" (tandi) is a name for bodily
> laziness; "stretching" (vijambhitā) is a name for bending of the body;
> "faintness after meals" (bhattasammada) is a name for giddiness after
> meals and feverishness after meals. And mental lassitude" (cetaso
> līnattaṃ) is a name for the sluggish state of the mind.
>
> Because of employing unwise bringing to mind much in regard to these
> [states] beginning with boredom, stiffness and torpor arise.
>
> (Dispeller of Delusion I 335)

So, it seems that arati is wholly mental; tandī is both bodily and mental (the Dispeller of Delusion later defines it as "bodily idleness due to defilement"); likewise vijambhitā, which is later defined as "bodily shifting due to defilement"; bhattasammada is wholly bodily; and cetaso līnattaṃ wholly mental.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to collect all the major sutta references on the 3rd hindrance.

Google is your friend: https://accesstoinsight.org/search_results.html?cx=006639875531220445029%3A2z3mhfokk-u&ie=UTF-8&q=Sloth+and+Drowsiness&sa=Search